# Obtener String JSON de un archivo de texto con muchos valores innecesarios C#

Tags: c#, json

estoy tratando de hacer una aplicacion para obtener el Discord ID de una cuenta de Discord, esto se puede haciendo un dumpeo de memoria al proceso padre de la aplicacion Discord, el id se encuentra en un json con otros valores de memoria

Como yo estoy dumpeando las strings de memoria, voy a obtener un archivo txt con la variable que necesito y muchisimas otras strings que no necesito

Para poder limpiar este archivo , intente utilizar

```
  string[] pathDump = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dir + @"\discord.txt");
                    foreach (var line in pathDump)
                    {
                   
                        if (line.Contains("\":[{\""))
                        {
                        }
                    }
```

El cual muestra un error de Newtonsoft.JSON cuando se encuentra una string json , el cual es el siguiente

**Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1**

Lo peor de todo, es que este archivo, a demas de tener valores "basura" tiene muchisimos otros JSON Strings las cuales no necesito

Adjunto la string que necesito sacar (que , obviamente, va a variar en diferentes pc debido al cambio de cuentas de discord)

`{"_state":{"users":[{"id":"1022681363201424660","avatar":"c06f02c432499c0de8334d4620cf39a8","username":"test","discriminator":"7569","tokenStatus":2,"pushSyncToken":null}],"canUseMultiAccountMobile":false},"_version":1}s`

Tambien adjunto un string dump del proceso, para que se den una idea de los valores que este contiene

https://anonfiles.com/Y4Pd42T2ya/Search_results_txt

Comment: ¿Es necesario hacer todo ese proceso inicial del proceso padre y demás? ¿No sería más simple utilizar la API?

Comment: no existe una api como tal

Comment: Quizás te sea de utilidad: https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no puedo hacerlo asi, ya investige y esta es la unica forma "fiable" , no puedo hacerlo por api por que tendria que pedirle al usuario que se logee o etc y quiero evitar eso, podrias ayudarme haciendolo de esta manera?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! querer evitar que se le loguee suena a que queres hacer algo encontra del propio usuario.. podrias especificar porque eso no es fiable, y porque necesitas evitar que se loguee??? te pregunto, porque aqui no damos ayuda para piratear o hackear sistemas (y por como lo planteas, eso parece, mejor aclarar para que no lo sea)...

Comment: No, no te puedo ayudar, al inicio pensé que desconocías de la API y bueno, bajo la descripción de lo que has respondido, coincido con la opinión de @gbianchi.

Comment: es para una tool de scaneo de modificaciones a juegos (ScreenShare Tool), no es viable ya que el scaneo tiene que durar lo menos posible y si le pido al usuario que se logee, tendria que detener el scaneo antes de poder mandarlo al servidor, toma el discord tag como "telemetria basica" asi el staff sabe a quien esta revisando

Adjunto pagina web del scanner https://golden.ml

Comment: aparte de que el usuario podria negar querer logearse en discord asi que seria una perdida de tiempo para ambos, tampoco estoy obteniendo datos sensibles ni nada por el estilo, solo es el discord tag del usuario